# When do we know if the infimum is also a (the) minumum of a set?

Tags: measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum, maxima-minima, almost-everywhere

For example, define for a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ the set

\begin{equation}
A_m = \{\omega \in \Omega: |f(\omega)|\leqslant m\}, \quad m\in\mathbb{R},
\end{equation}

for measurable functions $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{\overline{R}}$, where $\mathbb{\overline{R}}$ is the extended real line. Let

\begin{equation}
M = \{m \in \mathbb{R}: \mu({A_m}^c)=0\}.
\end{equation}

How do we know if $t = \inf \{M\} \in M$? By the definition of the infimum, we have that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $m\in M$ such that $m \leqslant t+\varepsilon$. Furthermore, since $M$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it must be that $t+\varepsilon \in M$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. This obviosly holds as $\varepsilon$ approaches zero, but how do I show that it also holds in the limit? I have tried defining $t_n = t+1/n$ and then letting $n \to \infty$, but I don't know where to go from there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: generally, you would need closedness of the set to go further.

Comment: Would you know how to go about proving that? I could show the complement is open, but I would have to prove that the $\inf M$ is not a part of the complement. Similarly, I think I could only prove that $M$ is not open if I assume that $\inf M \in M$. Or is there another way?